# Jedis Exception java.net.ConnectException: Address already in use

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I have a Jedis Server and I had made a separate RedisManager for managing the jedis connections. The code for RedisManager is as follows

```
package RedisServerPackage;
import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis;
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool;
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig;

public class RedisManager {
private static final RedisManager instance = new RedisManager();
private static final JedisPoolConfig poolConfig= new JedisPoolConfig();
private static JedisPool pool = null;
private RedisManager() {}

public final static RedisManager getInstance() {

    if(pool == null)
    {
        poolConfig.setMaxTotal(-1);
        pool = new JedisPool(poolConfig,"localhost");
    }

        return instance;
    }

    public void release() {
        pool.destroy();
    }

    public Jedis getJedis() {
        return pool.getResource();
    }

    public void returnJedis(Jedis jedis) {
        pool.returnResource(jedis);
     }
}
```

Now I execute my code where I have about 1000 clients hitting the server and performing certain operations using the PubSub model. I have monitored the redis-server and found that at a time, maximum 45 clients were active and max blocked clients were around 39. After running the client code for about 5 minutes or so, I get the exception

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:50)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:88)
    at RedisServerPackage.RedisManager.getJedis(RedisManager.java:31)
    at RedisServerPackage.RedisQueue.dequeue(RedisQueue.java:45)
    at RedisServerPackage.QueueProcessor.run(QueueProcessor.java:22)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Address already in use
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:148)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:75)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:1572)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:69)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:861)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363)
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:48)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:142)
    ... 12 more
```

I am not able to find out as to what is causing this exception. Also, I am reusing the jedis instances. An example code is

```
public void JedisExample(String temporaryString) {

        Jedis jedis = manage.getJedis();

        try {

        // Some code here

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }finally{
            manager.returnJedis(jedis);
            // manage is an instance of RedisManager class provided before.
        }
    }
```

Comment: For some reason your software is using the 4-argument connect. If it's under your control, use the 2-argument form. If it isn't, complain to the vendor. They have no business doing that.

Comment: @EJP sorry, I'm not familiar with what you are pointing out. Could you be more specific please ?

Comment: Was not able to solve the issue but found out that it maybe a hardware related issue and not a bug in the code after all. Executed the code on AWS machine with much superior config than my laptop and with nearly 10 times the clients hitting the server, but there was no exception.

Comment: I don't think this question is related with Netty. Removing the `netty` tag.

Comment: What is the size of your JedisPool? If you don't have enough resources, some clients would have to wait for free jedis instances from the pool. Maybe JedisPool does not handle back-pressure on so many clients. Did you try to use directly jedis instances manually created in each client?

Comment: Also where is your code where you create all your clients, are you using multithreading? Could be a lock / race condition issue, can you post the code of your test?

Comment: @zenbeni , I send a connect packet to the server and on receiving acknowledgement, I publish the packet. The code for publishing is in a message that just fills in the necessary arguments required for publish. I am using mqtt npm as a client.  `setInterval(sendMessage, 60, loadclient);`            **The send message is the function that is called after every 60 seconds to send a message for the loadClient whose connack has been received.**

Comment: @SachinMalhotra No, I don't think I could be possibly be any more specific actually. Just take a belated look at the Javadoc for `java.net.Socket`. Your request is just laziness frankly.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exception happening intermittently on MacOS when trying to load test my server app.

Turns out, the problem was related to the fact, that macOS only has 16K ports available that won't be released until socket TIME_WAIT is passed. The default timeout for TIME_WAIT is 15 seconds.

You can check yours via

```
sysctl net.inet.tcp.msl
```

To fix it temporarily to allow load testing, I used

```
sudo sysctl -w net.inet.tcp.msl=1000
```

this reduced TIME_WAIT to 1 second, allowing to create and release connections faster, which in turn enabled me to get Tomcat to convert REST requests to Redis PUBSUB messages at the rate of about 4000 qps and got 0 errors after 4 hours of bombardment under 16 concurrent Siege threads. Before, about 1% of requests would error out with the exception above.

The author of the question did not state the OS, but I hope this answer might help someone else running into similar situation, because this entry comes on top when searching for such exception in Jedis. Basically, check your TIME_WAIT when load testing, regardless of OS.

UPDATE

Warning. ***Do not do it in production!*** Ideally, increase it back to 15 seconds after load testing round on your workstations. Decreasing TIME_WAIT might be dangerous, because sockets become available faster after closing, and some delayed packets might arrive to a newly opened connection, causing unpredictable errors or even compromising security. Read more on the TCP/IP and TIME_WAITs, before you decide to follow the instructions above or consult your networking engineer.

Comment: The default setting for TIME_WAIT should be two *minutes.* Reducing it to 15 seconds is already insecure, and setting it to one second is really quite dangerous.

Comment: @user207421 - good point, I will update my answer with proper warning not to do it in production for the risk of stray packets meant for one connection to arrive to a new one. I think, however, that 15 seconds is long enough for modern connectivity. It's been years since I used anything with network latency more than 400ms (current ping to Australia from Toronto is ~310ms). I understand that it's more complicated than that, and 1s is too short, but 15 seconds is adequate.